# Updating colorbar bounds without removing the previous one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am plotting dynamic figures (with FuncAnimation) from matplotlib.animation but I struggle a lot for updating the boundaries of my colorbar. Of course I would like to update it without removing the current colorbar and drawing a new one, I just would like to update the boundaries of the current colorbar.

If the 1st boudnaries are from 0 to 1 for example, I would like to be able to change them from 0 to 100 or anything.

I am surprised that any information for this is so difficult to find, I've been searching the whole day and I feel a bit stupid and tired about this little thing consuming so much time :').

Any idea please ?

## This is a basic figure with a colorbar... I would like to update the boundaries of the colorbar (imagine the figure shown has been updated and the colorbar bounds don't fit anymore with the figure).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initial figure
data_array = np.random.rand(50,50)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
IMAGE = ax.imshow(data_array, animated = True)

# Color bar new axis
cbaxes = fig.add_axes() 
colorbar_bounds = np.linspace(np.min(data_array), np.max(data_array), 50)
colorbar_ticks = np.linspace(np.min(data_array), np.max(data_array) , 10)

# Colorbar
clb = fig.colorbar(IMAGE, cbaxes, orientation='vertical', boundaries=colorbar_bounds, ticks = colorbar_ticks)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I think there is no way to do this with the basic matplotlib colorbar options (at least I was not able to find any), I created my own colorbar.

Here is the solution.

Note :
The *animated=True* attribute is only necessary if you want a dynamic colorbar (auto updating in an animated figure canvas for example).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# INIT figure and axes
data_array = np.random.rand(50,50)
fig, [ax, cbax1, cbax2] = plt.subplots(1,3, sharex = False)
IMAGE = ax.imshow(data_array, animated = True)

# Colorbar boundaries and ticks
colorbar_bounds = np.linspace(np.min(data_array), np.max(data_array), 50)
colorbar_ticks = np.linspace(np.min(data_array), np.max(data_array) , 10)

# Classic Colorbar
classic_clb = fig.colorbar(IMAGE, cbax1, orientation='vertical', boundaries=colorbar_bounds, ticks = colorbar_ticks)
cbax1.set_title("Classic colorbar")

# Personalized (Dynamic or not as you want) Colorbar
myclb = colorbar_bounds[:, np.newaxis]
myclb = cbax2.imshow(myclb, animated = True, cmap = "nipy_spectral")
cbax2.set_title("My colorbar")

plt.show()
```

Then I can update my colorbar with : (forget this if you don't need your colorbar to change)

```py
myclb.set_array(mycb)
```